# Trouble getting IIS 8 Initialization working

Tags: iis, iis-8

I'm running IIS 8 and I'm trying to initialize my intranet MVC project when it is restarted. I am working off of [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/590865/how-can-i-warm-up-my-asp-net-mvc-webapp-after-an-app-pool-recycle) answer but I can't seem to get it to work. I see the IIS worker restarting when I recycle the app pool but I still get a slow load time, it's like the initialization page is not being called after the worker process starts.

IIS Application Pool
[image]

Site Advanced Settings

[image]

system.applicationHost/sites/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue was Windows Authentication. I disabled it and was able to see it run start up successfully after a recycle. This is where I found my info [link](http://forums.iis.net/t/1220721.aspx?Application%20Initialization%20Autostart%20Warmup%20with%20Windows%20Authentication%20fails)